# Calling PHP variables from inside a MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables, echo

I'm currently in the middle of working on a CMS system that builds the website straight from information saved in a MySQL database.

Here's the problem I'm having:

- Inside the CMS the user enters coding for a template
- the frontend of the site (frontend.php) calls the variable where the layout is stored ($template_header)
- The frontend also creates the variable $menu_code by pulling the menu code from the database, which was also stored via the CMS
- Inside of the template code, there has to be a break for this variable, when it is run by frontend.php it will be picked up.

This is what I've been trying:

inside frontend.php:

```
echo $template_header;
```

inside of $template_header:

```
<tr><td><center>'.$menu_code.'</center></td></tr>
```

What it should look like when frontend.php is run in the IE:

```
<tr><td><center><script>rest of menu coding in here</script></center></td></tr>
```

What it looks like when I do run it:

```
<tr><td><center>'.$menu_code.'</center></td></tr>
```

it displays it like text. It's probably a simple problem but any help would be much appreciated, on a tight deadline with this project and any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A simple replace would do the trick if I understand you correctly:

```
$template_data = "<tr><td><center>{%REPLACE_WITH_CONTENT%}</center></td></tr>";
$template_data = str_replace("{%REPLACE_WITH_CONTENT%}", $menu_code, $template_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you want [eval()](http://www.php.net/eval), which will interpret a string as PHP code, meaning any reference to $menu_code will be treated as PHP, and not text.

From the manual:

```
<?php
  $string = 'cup';
  $name = 'coffee';
  $str = 'This is a $string with my $name in it.';
  echo $str. "\n";
  eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
  echo $str. "\n";
?>
```

Outputs the following

```
This is a $string with my $name in it.
This is a cup with my coffee in it.
```

#### Warning!!!!

As pointed out in the comments, this method (eval()) opens us a door for major security-issues. This method will evaluate arbitrary code, which can be very dangerous.

Comment: and the inevitable note on eval(): eval() can execute arbitrary code, so if a user is able to put e.g. array_map('unlink', glob('*')) into your database php will happily delete all files in the cwd. If you want/have to avoid that use something that provides a well defined subset aka templating system.

Answer (score -1):

What you seem to be looking for is:

```
eval( $menu_code );
```