# PHP echo variables when I don't know which ones are going to show

Tags: php, string, variables

I have a calendar. The user selects which days he/she wants blocked. In the database, they are saved as an array with the name of the holiday:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:6:"easter";i:1;s:12:"thanksgiving";i:2;s:9:"christmas";}
```

In a file, I have strings with the dates of each one:

```
$thanksgiving = "
[11, 27, 2014],
[11, 26, 2015],
[11, 24, 2016],
[11, 23, 2017],
[11, 22, 2018],
[11, 28, 2019],
[11, 26, 2020],
[11, 25, 2021],
[11, 24, 2022],
[11, 23, 2023]
";

$christmas = "
[12, 25, 2014],
[12, 25, 2015],
[12, 25, 2016],
[12, 25, 2017],
[12, 25, 2018],
[12, 25, 2019],
[12, 25, 2020],
[12, 25, 2021],
[12, 25, 2022],
[12, 25, 2023]
";

$fourthofjuly = "
[07, 04, 2015],
[07, 04, 2016],
[07, 04, 2017],
[07, 04, 2018],
[07, 04, 2019],
[07, 04, 2020],
[07, 04, 2021],
[07, 04, 2022],
[07, 04, 2023]
";
```

etc...

```
$blocked_holidays is the array retrieved from the DB

When I try to echo it:
$blocked_string = implode(", $", $blocked_holidays);
$blocked_string = "[ $" . $blocked_string . " ]";

echo $blocked_string;

I get: [ $newyears, $thanksgiving, $christmas ]
```

How can I get it to echo the value of the string?

If I change it to:

```
$$thanksgiving = "
[11, 27, 2014],
[11, 26, 2015],
[11, 24, 2016],
[11, 23, 2017],
[11, 22, 2018],
[11, 28, 2019],
[11, 26, 2020],
[11, 25, 2021],
[11, 24, 2022],
[11, 23, 2023]
";

$$christmas = "
[12, 25, 2014],
[12, 25, 2015],
[12, 25, 2016],
[12, 25, 2017],
[12, 25, 2018],
[12, 25, 2019],
[12, 25, 2020],
[12, 25, 2021],
[12, 25, 2022],
[12, 25, 2023]
";

$$fourthofjuly = "
[07, 04, 2015],
[07, 04, 2016],
[07, 04, 2017],
[07, 04, 2018],
[07, 04, 2019],
[07, 04, 2020],
[07, 04, 2021],
[07, 04, 2022],
[07, 04, 2023]
";
```

and

```
$blocked_string = implode(", $", $$blocked_holidays);
echo $$blocked_string;
```

It echoes the dates, but only from the latest variable, not all of them.

Comment: Try checking out variables variable, $$variable

Comment: Couldn't get that to work. I did find this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php and tried to make it work. The closest I got, it would only display the last variable string.

Comment: Check the edit..that's my attempt at variables variable.

Comment: This answered the question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051775/calling-php-variables-from-inside-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

```
$blocked_holidays=array("a", "b", "c");
$a=1; $b=2; $c=3; //testing values
```

```
 $blocked_string=array();
 foreach ($blocked_holidays as $value) {
    array_push($blocked_string, ${$value});
 }
 echo '['.implode($blocked_string, ',').']';
```

**EDIT**

I think i get what you are trying to do:

```
$blocked_string=implode(", $", $blocked_holidays);
$blocked_string=eval('echo "[$'.$blocked_string.']";');
echo $blocked_string;

//or simply
$blocked_string=eval('echo "[$'.implode(", $", $blocked_holidays).']";');
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm trying to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051775/calling-php-variables-from-inside-a-mysql-database